# How to debugging php on a VPS using phpStorm and Xdebug?

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have trying to get this done for days...and reading through about 20 tutorials, documents, etc...but still no luck.

Here is the thing. I installed wordpress(just for example, can be any php program) on my VPS, and hoping to debug it from my macbook and my desktop. This is clearly a remote debugging thing. So I here is what I done:

1.Installed right version of xdebug and located its .so file on VPS.
2.Changing php.ini and 20-xdebug.ini file on VPS, my settings currently are:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9200
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.var_display_max_data=10000
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=20
xdebug.show_exception_trace=0
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
;xdebug.remote_host=202.84.93.66
```

The last line, which is comment out is my desktop IP address, where I run phpStorm. Based on xdebug's documents, if you set remote_connect_back=1, you won't need this host ip to be specifici.

3. On phpStorm Side, I "start new project from existing code, and specificy the source root on VPS, map it with one of my local dest. PhpStorm just downloaded all the files and after setting up "Automatic upload", the sync is perfect.
4. On phpStorm side, I specificy the PHP intercepter as the remote one on my VPS.
5. On phpStorm side, I changed my debugging port to 9200, as same as the one I using on VPS.
6. Using the booklet method phpStorm provide, I put them on my firefox bootkmarklet.
7. Click listen button on phpStorm, set breakpoint, go to firefox open the page, click 'start debuging', refresh.....BUT NOTHING HAPPENS!
8. I also tried to using the tranditional methods, which set a run configration way as both php-webapplication or php-remote-debug...but still not working.
9. At php storm, the web debug validation, I could pass all the testing there though....

Can anyone help me with this? I think I must be doing wrong on some very fundation part since I saw all the tutorial are so simple set, but this already took me about 3 days to figure out....

Thanks!

Comment: So ... what your xdebug log says about it? So far it most likely your local/remote firewall (it's xdebug (server) who connects to client (PhpStorm) and not other way around). I also hope that you have changed xdebug port in PhpStorm in the right place (not like some other people around -- anywhere were they see "port").

Comment: The log is really interesting... It do log sometimes, but the problem is I can't find out when it was logged. I think when i do "Listen" on phpStorm and click the "start debug" booklet it won't trigger the log at all. But if I select a file, for example index.php, and right click and click debug, this time it will log something, most time is "Connection time out" sort of staff...For the port, I changed at "Preference->PHP->debug", where original is 9000, and I read some guys said that this port maybe confict with php-cgi or something, so I changed it 9200.

Comment: 1) Check that IP and port in log do match with what you have got. 2) Check your firewall (login into your VPS and try to connect back to your local computer on xdebug port using `telnet`, for example. If unable -- wrong IP/port is closed/firewall) 3) You can use `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` to debug every single request ... or try placing `xdebug_break();` to trigger breakpoint programatically.

Comment: If firewall is the issue -- try debugging over SSH tunnel.